# After adding to a list, can only print most recent object

Tags: python, list, class

I want to add an object to a list, the object contains both a title and an artist.
The object adds fine, but when I want to print all the objects from my list I get an error. When doing my method as shown below, it prints only the most recent object added twice.

```
listOfBooks = []

class Book:
    title = "No Title"
    author = "No Author"


    def myBook(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author

    def get(self):
        return self.title + self.author



book = Book()
for _ in range(0,2):
    titleInput = input("Enter a title: ")
    authorInput = input("Enter an author: ")
    book.myBook(titleInput, authorInput)
    listOfBooks.append(book)



for i in range(0,len(listOfBooks)):
    print(listOfBooks[i].get())
```

Comment: What error? Please show us the traceback.

Comment: Because the book=Book() should be inside and not outside the for loop. In this case you are overriding the same object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new `Book` instance in every loop iteration. Move `book = Book()` inside the loop:

```
for _ in range(0,2):
    book = Book()    # Here
    titleInput = input("Enter a title: ")
    authorInput = input("Enter an author: ")
    book.myBook(titleInput, authorInput)
    listOfBooks.append(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have some *instance variables* (title and author) that are specific to each individual `Book` object. The typical way to set these while creating your instances is to ask for them in the object's `__init__()` method, so your code would look like this:

```
listOfBooks = []


class Book:
    title = "No Title"
    author = "No Author"

    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author

    def get(self):
        return self.title + self.author

for _ in range(0,2):
    titleInput = input("Enter a title: ")
    authorInput = input("Enter an author: ")
    # Calling the class calls the __init__ method and creates the
    #   instance
    book = Book(titleInput, authorInput)
    listOfBooks.append(book)

for i in range(0,len(listOfBooks)):
    print(listOfBooks[i].get())
```

This gives the same results as Yu Hao's answer:

```
Enter a title: Green Eggs

Enter an author: Seuss

Enter a title: Moby Dick

Enter an author: Melville
Green EggsSeuss
Moby DickMelville
```

Answer (score 1):

1. boot initial(book = Book()) is out of the for loop, so, actually, you edit the same Book instance every loop, you can use id() to have a look.
2. for list, elements can be same, so regarding your for loop, the same object book is appended into listOfBooks for twice, that's why print the same output for twice.